# RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited asyncio.run in separate thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I've built a little aiohttp based spider. Here's some abbreviated code:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from threading import Thread

class Spider:
    def __init__(self, urls):
        self.urls = urls
        self.start()

    async def fetch(self, session, url):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            await self.handle_status(response) # undefined here for brevity
            return await self.render_body(response) # undefined here for brevity

    async def process_urls(self):
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            tasks = {self.fetch(session, url) for url in self.urls}
            for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
                raw_data = await task
                data = self.extract_data(*raw_data) # sync method undefined here for brevity
                await self.store_data(data) # undefined here for brevity

    def start(self) -> None:
        try:
            asyncio.run(self.process_urls())
        except RuntimeError:  # loop already running
            x = Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(self.process_urls(),))
            x.start()
            x.join()
```

The start method is intended to start an asyncio loop, but if one is already running, then it starts a new loop in a new Thread.

The code works whether run from an existing loop or not. But if run from an existing loop (e.g. with pytest.mark.asyncio()), I get this warning:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Spider.process_urls' was never awaited x.join()

Is this warning something I should be concerned about?

Is there a better way to handle this that would not cause this warning?

I've tried loop = asyncio.get_running_loop() with loop.create_task(self.process_urls()) instead of creating a new thread, but this fails with:

> RuntimeError: coroutine ignored GeneratorExit

I've tried nest-asyncio, but my primary use case involves another library that uses uvloop, so nest-asyncio is not compatible.

Comment: I think the problem is that in your `try` block you create the coroutine before the `RuntimeError` is raised. So the task is never cancelled because the `RuntimeError` is raised inside `run` before it cleans up the running loop. Maybe cancel your task manually inside you exception handler to get rid of the warning.

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword, I don't think that is the issue. The warning seems to point to x.join as the culprit, rather than asyncio.run from the try block. Additionally,
`try: asyncio.get_running_loop(); except: asyncio.run(); else: Thread` produces the same error pointing to x.join()

Comment: Actually even though x.join() is listed, the code line number is the `x = Thread` line...

Comment: The `RuntimeWarning` is raised on `x.join()` because this is the point in your code where the loop terminates. Only then can the loop know, that your coroutine was never awaited. Does your program work as you expect other than this warning? I can not say anything about the ignored `GeneratorExit`. Maybe a complete traceback would be helpful. However, I'm pretty sure appending a new task to a running loop would be better design than spinning up a new loop in a thread. But that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I admit, I can't offer you full explanation on the reasons why that warning is there but I can offer you code that is warning free:

```py
def start(self) -> None:
    try:
        asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        asyncio.run(self.process_urls())
    else:
        # Since the loop is already instantiated we can use it with our own
        # tasks without creating another thread.
        # asyncio.create_task(self.process_urls())
        x = Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(self.process_urls(),))
        x.start()
        x.join()
```

Possibly, you get `RuntimeWarning` because your code creates new Thread (and BTW, that warning gets produced even when you switch to `asyncio.create_task()`) during handling of the exception where "normal laws of physics" don't apply. But again, that's only my guess so take it with a grain of salt.